# How do I use cucumber profile to dynamically use different environment hostname, testdata, testGroup. I am using cucumber, java, maven

Tags: maven, cucumber

I have test cases written in feature files. The test cases are tagged per requirements.
I want these test cases to be executed on different environments, using maven command, by passing profile name.
Each profile will have hostname, username, password for particular environment.
How do I achieve this?

```
@stage_ready
Feature: GUI Tests
Background:
    Given the site <hostname> is reached using "Chrome" browser
    When maximize window
    And credentials <user_host> is typed into the "sd_username_editbox" 
    And credentials <password_host> is typed into the "sd_password_editbox"
    And the "sd_login_button" button is clicked
```

CommandLine:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”–tags @stage_ready” -p profile_name
```

I want to know how to write profile, which will have parameters like hostname, user_host, password_host for different profiles and be dynamically used in the cucumber steps, that I have marked in angle brackets for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Cucumber documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/configuration/#profiles):
"Profiles are not available in Java."

If you want to pass arguments to Maven, you can use [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

For example (from the Maven link above):

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>appserverConfig-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <appserver.home>/path/to/dev/appserver</appserver.home>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>appserverConfig-dev-2</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>dev-2</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <appserver.home>/path/to/another/dev/appserver2</appserver.home>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ..
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, Can anyone tell me how can we use maven profile with cucumber ? I have created profile in POM but it is getting executed after cucumber tests. I expect then to get executed before tests so that maven ant tasks would be finished before test begins. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311533/maven-ant-task-not-getting-executed-while-running-cucumber-tests